# Purpose of using "? super T" in Java8 Consumer andThen

Tags: java, java-8

I was looking at Java8's functional Interface **Consumer**. I can see a default method **andThen**. I understood that the method is used to chain consumer's together. Below is the code of andThen method:

```
default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(after);
    return (T t) -> { accept(t); after.accept(t); };
}
```

**Question:** Why only the type & SuperType of element (? super T) are allowed in the Consumer argument of **andThen** method. I want to understand the purpose of the usage here.

I would help me in improving my understanding of Generics.

Comment: I understood "What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?" . What i asked here is what is the purpose of using "<? super T>" in andThen here. Why to add restrictions to allow only the type and superType in the Consumer of andThen.

Comment: So you are saying this is not a duplicate. OK, I thought you were asking about that, but it seems you want to know about this specific case. Reopened. Let's see  what others have to say.

Comment: In short, the lower bound is there to allow a consumer of more general objects. Consider i.e. a consumer that adds an element to a `List<Integer>`. This could be i.e. `Consumer<Integer> ci = list::add;`. Now, besides adding that element to the list, you might also want to print that element to the screen. If you happen to have that second consumer already defined i.e. `Consumer<Object> co = System.out::println;`, you wouldn't be able to chain both consumers by using `Consumer.andThen` if `Consumer.andThen` accepted just a `Consumer<T>`, because `co` is not a `Consumer<Integer>` (as `ci`).

Comment: Thanks Federico !! I got confused but understood now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a `Consumer<Dog>` and a `Consumer<Animal>`.  Of course, you can pass a `Dog` into either of these `accept` methods, as a `Dog` is an `Animal`.

However, in Java, there is no inheritance relationship between `Consumer<Dog>` and `Consumer<Animal>`, for reasons that have been discussed on other questions on this site.  So to allow us to chain any other `Consumer` that will accept a `Dog`, we need to declare it as a `Consumer<? super Dog>`.

Comment: But why not use "andThen(Consumer<T> after)" or "andThen(Consumer<? extends T> after)" here ? I am trying to understand things here.

Comment: @SahilGupta `andThen(Consumer<T> after)` would forbid to chain a `Consumer<Animal> ca` after a `Consumer<Dog> cd`: `cd.andThen(ca)` - but a `Consumer<Animal>` is a valid consumer for all `Dog`s. `andThen(Consumer<? extends T> after)` would allow `ca.andThen(cd)`. But what if the element that is fed into `ca` is a `Cat`? You would then feed the `Cat` into the `Consumer<Dog>`

Comment: @ThomasKläger : Thanks. That answers my question :)